# pandas joining strings in a group, skipping na values

Tags: pandas, join

I'm using a combination of `str.join` (let's call the column joined `col_str`) and `groupby` (Let's call the grouped col `col_a`) in order to summarize data row-wise.

`col_str`, may contain `nan` values. Unsurprisingly, and as seen in `str.join` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html), joining nan will result in an empty string:

```
   df = df.join(df['col_a'].map(df.groupby('col_a')['col_str'].unique().str.join(', '))
```

[image]

To mitigate this, I tried to convert `col_str` to string (e.g.  `df['col_str'] = df['col_str'].astype(str)` ). But then, empty values now literally have a string `nan` value, hence considered non empty.

Not only that `str.join` now includes `nan` strings, but also other calculations over the script, that rely on those nans, are ruined.

To address that, I thought about converting just the non-empty values as follows:

```
df['col_str'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['col_str']), df['col_str'],
                                                   df['col_str'].astype(str))
```

But now `str.join` return empty values again :-(

So, I tried `fillna('')` and even `dropna()`. None provided me with the desired results.

You get the vicious cycle here, right?
`astype(str)` => `nan` strings in join and calculations ruined
Leaving as-is => `join.str` returns empty results.

Thanks for your assistance!

---

Edit:
Data is read from a csv. Sample:
[image]

Code to test -

```
   df = pd.read_csv('/Users/goidelg/Downloads/sample_data.csv', low_memory=False)
   print("---Original DF ---")
   print(df)
   print("---Joining NaNs as NaN---")
   print(df.join(df['col_a'].map(df.groupby('col_a')['col_str'].unique().str.join(', ')).rename('strings_concat')))
   print("---Convertin col to str---")
   df['col_str'] = df['col_str'].astype(str)
   print(df.join(df['col_a'].map(df.groupby('col_a')['col_str'].unique().str.join(', ')).rename('strings_concat')))
```

And results for the script:
[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample data to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) or [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2],
                   'col_str':['a','b','c','d',np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,'a', 's']})


df1 = (df.join(df['col_a'].map(df[df['col_str'].notna()]
                                 .groupby('col_a')['col_str'].unique()
                                 .str.join(', ')). rename('labels')))
print (df1)
   col_a col_str labels
0      1       a      a
1      2       b   b, s
2      3       c      c
3      4       d      d
4      1     NaN      a
5      2     NaN   b, s
6      3     NaN      c
7      4     NaN      d
8      1       a      a
9      2       s   b, s
```

---

```
df2 = (df.join(df['col_a'].map(df.dropna(subset=['col_str'])
                                 .groupby('col_a')['col_str']
                                 .unique().str.join(', ')).rename('labels')))
print (df2)
   col_a col_str labels
0      1       a      a
1      2       b   b, s
2      3       c      c
3      4       d      d
4      1     NaN      a
5      2     NaN   b, s
6      3     NaN      c
7      4     NaN      d
8      1       a      a
9      2       s   b, s
```

Comment: I read the df from a csv. Maybe that can be the reason?

Comment: @goidelg - hmmm, hard to know. But is possible test it, answer will be edited.

Comment: I added a sample to the original question. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @goidelg - can you test my solution in answer if no missing values there?

Comment: Woohoo! Yes, ```notna()``` did the trick. I had to do some adaptations to it so it'll be sound with other parts of the code though:
``` df = df.join(df['col_a']. map(df[df['col_str'].notna()].groupby('col_a')['col_str'].unique().str.join(', ')). rename('labels'))```

Thanks so much smart person!

Comment: @goidelg - added 2 solutions - with `df.dropna(subset=['col_str'])` not woking same like `df[df['col_str'].notna()]`